# SMS to contacts with multiple numbers

Tags: sms

I use to forward SMS to many contacts, most of those contacts have multiple numbers with one number as default.

**Handcent**
When I select a group to send a message, handcent asks me to choose number for each contact with multiple numbers.
**GO SMS**
It does the same as handcent
**Pansi SMS**
It picks the number randomly

Is there anyway it can pick default number automatically, or select the 'home' or 'mobile' number automatically?

Or is there any alternate application, as good as handcent, which can do that?

Comment: Have you tried asking one of the developers of those apps if that can be added?  Speaking personally as an app developer, I love hearing from users with suggestions to improve functionality or usability since I can't envision all possible usage scenerios myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version of handcent  with its group sms plugin does the job perfectly.

Comment: Why down vote, it works perfectly

Comment: I did not mark this answer down, but handcent with group plugin (10) still asks to confirm which phone number to add.